# Ordenar valores graficados

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

Estoy graficando unos valores de un diccionario que convertí en dataframe para graficarlo mas fácil. En la grafica muestra los valores bien pero desordenados, me gustaría que estuviera de forma descendente, de mayor a menor, pero aun no he podido ordenarlos, no se si debo ordenarlos en el diccionario o en el dataframe. De ambas maneras no he podido

codigo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[key, total[key]] for key in total.keys()], columns=['Letra', 'Frecuencia'])

letra = df['Letra']
frecuencia = df['Frecuencia']

plt.bar(letra,frecuencia)
plt.xlabel("Caracteres alfanuméricos", size = 16,)
plt.ylabel("Frecuencia, valor", size = 16)
plt.show()
```

salida:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

valores del dataframe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se puede ver esta desordenado...

**Nota:**

obtuve un solución y el resultado fue este, aunque le agrege algunas cositas visuales de mas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega la imagen final para ver como resultó.

Comment: Así se entiende mucho mejor. Incluso podrías descartar los valores muy bajos. Cualquier letra/simbolo que no aparezca es que representa menos del X%.

Comment: Esa parte si no se como hacerla, me explicas por favor, me parece muy interesante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el método sort_values

```
df.sort_values(by='Frecuencia', ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me sirvió